# C++, Why does my program hangs when I use this kind of array to store data?

Tags: c++

My program just simply hangs when I am trying to enter any coordinate for x pt.1.

Anyone can help me please??

```
// shape.h
#include <string>
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H 1
using namespace std;

class Shape
{

protected:
    int x, y;
    string name;
public:
// a simple inline constructor
    Shape(int new_x, int new_y, string new_name): x(new_x), y(new_y), name(new_name)
    {
        return;
    };

    virtual ~Shape()
    {
        return;
    };
// inline getter/setter functions
    string getName() { return name; };
    void setName(string new_name)
    {
        name = new_name;
    }

    int getX() { return x; };
    void setX(int set_x)
    {
        x = set_x;
    }

    int getY() { return y; };
    void setY(int set_y)
    {
        y = set_y;
    }

    void toString();
};
#endif
```

the shape header. this program is about inheritance too..

```
// square.h
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H 1
#include <string>
#include "Shape.h"
using namespace std;

class Square : public Shape
{
protected:
int size;
public:
// a c'tor that calls the parent class's c'tor
Square(int new_x, int new_y, string new_name): Shape(new_x, new_y, new_name)
{
    return;
};

void setXY();
Square *arraySquare[1];
};

void Square::setXY()
{
int count = 0;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    cout<<"Please enter x-ordinate of pt. "<<i+1<<" : ";
    cin>>x;
    arraySquare[count]->setX(x);
    cout<<"Please enter y-ordinate of pt. "<<i+1<<" : ";
    cin>>y;
    arraySquare[count]->setY(y);
    count++;
}
}

#endif
```

square header.. a subclass of shape..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Shape.h"
#include "Square.h"
using namespace std;

class Main
{
public:
    void mainMenu();
    char menuChoice;
    void stringToUpper(string &s);
};

void stringToUpper(string &s)
{
    for(unsigned int l = 0; l < s.length(); l++)
    {
        s[l] = toupper(s[l]);
    }
}

void Main::mainMenu()
{
    cout<<"Welcome to Main program!"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"1)   Input data"<<endl;
    cout<<"2)   2"<<endl;
    cout<<"3)   3"<<endl;
    cout<<"4)   4"<<endl;
    cout<<"Q)   Enter 'Q' to quit"<<endl<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    char menuChoice;

    bool quit=false;
    Main main;
    Square *square;

    string shape, special;

    while ( !quit )
    {
        main.mainMenu();
        cout<<"Please enter your choice : ";
        cin>>menuChoice;
        menuChoice = toupper(menuChoice);

        switch(menuChoice)
        {
            case '1':
            cout<<endl<<"[ Input data ]"<<endl;
            cout<<"Please enter name of shape : "<<endl;
            cin>>shape;
            stringToUpper(shape);
            if(shape=="SQUARE")
            {
                square->setXY();
            }
            break;
            case '2':
            cout<<"Print"<<endl<<endl;
            break;           
            case '3':
            cout<<"You choosen 3"<<endl<<endl;
            break;                   
            case '4':
            cout<<"You choosen 4"<<endl<<endl;
            break;
            case 'Q':
            cout<<"You have chosen to quit!"<<endl<<endl;
            quit=true;
            exit(0);                 
            default:
            cout<<"Invalid entry!"<<endl<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the face of the program..

it just hangs whenever i run it and enter the first coordinate x. Anyone can help?

Comment: The variable `square` is an uninitialised `Square*` and is dereferenced, causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Also you're going past the end of `arraySquare` which is undefined behavior too.

Comment: Try using a debugger to see what happens. Could be it's not because of the array at all, but that cin is in error state.

Comment: what kidn of debugger there is? I am using Quincy 2005 to do this..

Comment: @hmjd / dan , is there any way to do this better? I need to store four points of the square points. that is why I am doing this.

Comment: my square->setXY() is creating a lot of problems. Even with no arrays back at my Square.h, square->setXY() is hanging my program.

Comment: Anyone can help me fix this? I am new to C++.. need help.. been figuring out for the past 2 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program hangs because it access unallocated objects. Each time you see a pointer declaration, you must apply 3 rules: a) Is it set to a default value? b) Is it allocated/assigned? c) Is it deleted?

In the class Square, you have declared this data member:

```
Square *arraySquare[1];
```

So, an object of type Square have an array of 1 pointer to a Square. (I believe you should have Shape instead of Square.) You have to allocate a Square and put it in `arraySquare` (rule b). Since you have a pointer, you should set it to `NULL` (rule a) in the constructor and you have to delete it in the destructor (rule c).

Then in `setXY()` you want to set 4 pairs of X&Y, but `arraySquare` only have space for 1 instance and it have not been allocated. One simple fix is to modify the definition of arraySquare to have an array of 4 pointers instead of only 1. Before setting the X & Y in the for loop, you have to allocate a Square instance if it is still NULL (to allow `setXY()` to be called more than once on the same object). Now that you have 4 pointers, you have to update the constructor to set all 4 to NULL and update the destructor to delete all 4.

In `main()`, you also use a pointer. I leave it to you to apply the rules to it.

NB: It would be clearer to use a type Point, because we normally say "a square have 4 corners/points". And by using Square an `arraySquare`, each corner of a Square have its own "name".

Comment: I have another question too, how do I call setXY() in Assn2? I believe Square * square; and then calling square->setXY() is also hanging up my program. How do I solve this?

Comment: Assn2? Do you mean main()? Have you applied the 3 rules to that square pointer?

Comment: Yes main. I really do not know how to start. Every single thing I tried to do, to change, it just simply hangs the program. Guess I am going to pass up nothing this assignment and just fail it.

Comment: You have to understand what is a pointer. Maybe this can help:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/418/
The pointer is a really important feature in C/C++. If you do not learn how to use them, you will have a lot of difficulties with many more concepts.